# WP_query minimum post results

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I’m currently looking into a solution to make a search query based on a minimum number of results, also when not all search options match.

Ideal situation;

I have made a custom post type and added a couple of shoes with different colors and sizes. And I am querying with WP_Query() for ‘blue shoes’ and ‘size 8’. When I do this query, I only get 3 blue-colored shoes in size 8. Now I want to add 7 more equal shoes in size 8 to get a total of 10 shoes.

How would I do this within Wordpress in combination with Advanced Custom Fields?

I have made a custom WP_Query based on the WP_query() method. And made an array to store all post-results based on the first query and if the length of that array is not equal to 10 it will do an additional query.

So far so good, but then I get duplicate results:

=> I get the 3 already found blue-colored shoes in size 8, and again in the second query all the size 8 shoes including the already found shoes (from the first query).

See my code below;

```
$shoe_array = array();

$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'my_shoes',
    'meta_query'    => array(   
        'relation'      => 'AND',           
        array(
            'key'       => 'size',
            'value'     => 8,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'color',
            'value'     => 'blue',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
);

$shoes = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $shoes->posts;

foreach($posts as $post) {

    array_push($shoe_array, $post->post_name);

}

if (count($shoe_array) > 9) {

    echo 'Result of found shoes: ';
    print_r($shoe_array);   

} else {

    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'my_shoes',
        'meta_query'    => array(   
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'size',
                'value'     => 8,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC'
    );

    $extra_shoes = new WP_Query( $args );
    $posts = $extra_shoes->posts;

    foreach($posts as $post) {

        array_push($shoe_array, $post->post_name);

    }

    echo 'Result of found shoes: ';
    print_r($shoe_array);

}
```

Anyone know how to make the query 'smarter'?

Please feel free to ask me additional questions if needed. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I understand that you want a result that combine the 3 reals results + 7 other results, is that what you want ?

Comment: @SouhailV Yes, that is exactly what I want to accomplish. The other results should be 'almost the same' so in this case without the meta-value 'blue'.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that code can help you :

```
<?php

$shoe_array = array();

$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'my_shoes',
    'meta_query'    => array(   
        'relation'      => 'AND',           
        array(
            'key'       => 'size',
            'value'     => 8,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'color',
            'value'     => 'blue',
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'fields'         => 'ids'
);

$shoes = get_posts( $args ) ;

$count10 = 10 - count($shoes) ;

$args2 = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'my_shoes',
        'meta_query'    => array(   
            'relation'      => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'size',
                'value'     => 8,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE'
            )
        ),
        'orderby'           => 'date',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'post__not_in' => $shoes,
        'posts_per_page' => $count10 ,
        'fields'         => 'ids'
    );

    $shoes8 = get_posts( $args2 ) ;

    $post_ids = array_merge( $shoes, $shoes8);

    print_r($post_ids);

?>
```

Comment: Many thanks @souhailV , the "post__not_in" variable was the key to this issue!  Glad you could point me into that direction! Best regards!

Comment: you are welcome @0611nl, thanks for mention my answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

So just add a does not equal condition to color is blue

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'my_shoes',
    'meta_query'    => array(   
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'       => 'size',
            'value'     => 8,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        )
        array(
            'key'       => 'color',
            'value'     => 'blue',
            'compare'   => '!='
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'           => 'date',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
);
```